# How do you add/remove HTML ids/classes to elements using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css-selectors

I somewhat understand how to add elements with text to an HTML document using JavaScript. I'm just looking for a way to add an id/class to an element that is created from a function that's triggered by a event attribute in a form.

I want to display the following:

```
    
    #error {
    border: 0.5em red solid;
    }
    
    #correct {
    border: 0.5em green solid;
    }
    
<p id="error"> Must have at least one checkbox checked</p>
<p id="correct"> At least one checkbox is checked</p>
```

Please provide an example function that's triggered by an onsubmit event attribute utilized in a form element.

Comment: did you do a quick search on Stackoverflow? These are very basic operations and have been answered before.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a class to an element using `classList.add`. Here is an example:
**HTML File**

```
.errorStyle {
    border: 0.5em red solid;
}
    
.correctStyle {
    border: 0.5em green solid;
}
    
<p id="error"> Must have at least one checkbox checked</p>
<p id="correct"> At least one checkbox is checked</p>
<button onclick="change()">Submit</button>
```

**JS Function**

```
function change() {
  var element = document.getElementById("error");
  element.classList.add("errorStyle");
  element.classList.add("correctStyle");
}
```